# Search Engine Bug

Tags: php, search

I have a bug in my php&mysql search engine.
It was a simple search engine, but I have decided to upgrade this search engine by adding the image of the required product to the results, so the problem I have is, ***the image of the first product will be the image of all the other products.***

**Here the code:**

```
<?php
include ('Connections/connect.php');

// collect

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("La Recherche est impossible");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    /*Afichage de L'image*/
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct='$product'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    foreach($row as $results) {
        $nom = $row[6];
    }

    $dir = "images/";
    if ($row[6] == 0) {
        $image_r = "images/none.png";
    }

    if ($row[6] != 0) {
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".JPEG")) {
            $image_r.= $dir . $nom . ".JPEG";
        }
        else
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".jpg")) {
            $image_r.= $dir . $nom . ".jpg";
        }
        else
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".jpeg")) {
            $image_r.= $dir . $nom . ".jpeg";
        }
    }

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = "Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!";
    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $sProduct = $row['sProduct'];
            $output.= '<div><ul><li><a target="_blanc" href="product.php?product=' . $sProduct . '" title="' . $sProduct . '"><img src="' . $image_r . '">' . $sProduct . '</a></li></ul></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

here's all the source code, hope I find some Help!
And Thanks to all members of stackexchange.

Comment: this part `foreach($row as $results) { $nom = $row[6]; }` is suspicious..

Comment: why it is suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling your image statements outside the loop. Get rid of the first loop and move all image processing into the second. Sample attached:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("La Recherche est impossible");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%' OR sSort LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    /*Afichage de L'image*/
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sProduct='$product'");
    // this query looks redundant. your search query should include an image since you're selecting all from that table in both cases

    $dir = "images/";

    if ($count == 0) {
        $output = "Aucun Résultat Pour Cette Recherche!";
    }
    else 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $image_r = "images/none.png";
        if ($row[6] != 0) {
            $nom = $row[6];
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".JPEG")) {
            $image_r = $dir . $nom . ".JPEG";
        }
        else
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".jpg")) {
            $image_r = $dir . $nom . ".jpg";
        }
        else
        if (file_exists($dir . $nom . ".jpeg")) {
            $image_r = $dir . $nom . ".jpeg";
        }
        }

            $sProduct = $row['sProduct'];
            $output.= '<div><ul><li><a target="_blanc" href="product.php?product=' . $sProduct . '" title="' . $sProduct . '"><img src="' . $image_r . '">' . $sProduct . '</a></li></ul></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Also, mysql_functions are deprecated. You should switch to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: many more problems await you if you continue using mysql_ functions.

Comment: probably because $row[6] is always 0. if you var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($query)) what do you get? You should update your question with the results. no wait - $nom is undefined

Comment: sorry, i updated. though my example is looking badly formatted - I just defined $nom to be $row[6] in the loop

Comment: withe the var `dump(mysql_fetch_array($query))` it shows the name of the images correctly

Comment: Thanks this works totaly normale, this the best answer, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please use something like this:

```
$searchq        = $_POST['search'];
$searchq        = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
$escapedSearchQ = mysql_real_escape( $searchq ); 
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * "
                    . "  FROM tProduct "
                    . " WHERE sProduct LIKE '%" . $escapedSearchQ . "%' "
                    . "    OR sSearch  LIKE '%" . $escapedSearchQ . "%' "
                    . "    OR sSort    LIKE '%" . $escapedSearchQ . "%' "
                    ) 
          or die("La Recherche est impossible")
          ;
```

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aPHP) provides details how to write secure PHP-code [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aPHP).

Comment: you are missing the `$` on each of the `escapedSearchQ` in the query